# Expo: UIManager throwing warning UIManager

Tags: react-native, expo, uimanager

This message seems like some package is using UIManager["RCTView"] which is no longer supported but I am not sure how to fix this

> Accessing view manager configs directly off UIManager via UIManager['RCTView'] is no longer supported. Use
>   UIManager.getViewManagerConfig('RCTView') instead.
>   - node_modules/expo/build/environment/muteWarnings.fx.js:17:23 in warn
>   - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/UIManager.js:164:12 in get
>   - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Utilities/defineLazyObjectProperty.js:42:18
>   in getValue
>   - node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/GestureHandler.js:46:10 in 
>   - node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
>   - node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/index.js:3:0 in 
>   - node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
>   - node_modules/react-navigation-stack/src/views/StackView/StackViewLayout.js:19:0
>   in 
>   - node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
>   - node_modules/react-navigation-stack/src/views/StackView/StackView.js:4:0
>   in 
>   - node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
>   - node_modules/react-navigation-stack/src/navigators/createStackNavigator.js:3:0
>   in 
>   - node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
>   - node_modules/react-navigation-stack/src/index.js:9:18 in createStackNavigator
>   - node_modules/react-navigation/src/react-navigation.js:107:45 in createStackNavigator
>   * src/components/Navigation/Navigators.js:27:29 in 
>   - node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
>   * src/components/Navigation/index.js:4:0 in 
>   - node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
>   * src/containers/app/index.js:12:0 in 
>   - node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
>   * App.js:1:0 in 
>   - node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
>   - node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js:4:0 in 
>   - node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:331:6 in loadModuleImplementation
>   - node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:197:45 in guardedLoadModule
>   * null:null in global code

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by react-navigation module. I assume you're using expo sdk 33.

1. If you're using react-navigation v3, you can downgrade to version 2 which should solve the problem. Or..
2. Update your expo-cli to latest version. Install latest react-navigation. Then Install additional modules as follows.

expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated

[As found in the Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html)

Comment: Option 2 (upgrading) is the recommended way and don't forget to clear the bundler cache (expo start -c)

Comment: On SDK 34.0.0 I still have the same problem, with: "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0", "react-native-reanimated": "^1.1.0" and "react-navigation": "^3.2.3". Any suggestions? `yarn outdated` does not show any of above as upgradeable.

Comment: downgrade to "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.3.0". if you choose the package version with “^” and you are cleaning your node_modules, NPM will upgrade to the latest version (1.4.1) when you are doing NPM install

Answer (score 1):

downgrade to "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.3.0". if you choose the package version with “^” and you are cleaning your node_modules, NPM will upgrade to the latest version (1.4.1) when you are doing NPM install